CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup
I have Jmeter 5.6.3 Installed on linux ubuntu using command line and need to use ConcurrencyThreadGroup. So I install the ConcurrencyThreadGroup.jar and move it to lib/ext folder, but when I run the test plan in Non Gui mode I get the following error: "CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup". So, I need your help to run the test.

Most probably you're running a different JMeter version, not the one which has the plugin installed.
It might be the case you've installed JMeter from Ubuntu repositories and it's in your shell PATH so instead of running jmeter you should run ./jmeter.sh from "bin" folder of your JMeter 5.6.3 installation.
Also be informed that recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using JMeter Plugins Manager
Example command line to install JMeter 5.6.3 and Custom Thread Groups on Ubuntu and run the test:
export JMETER_VERSION=5.6.3 \
&& export PLUGINS=jpgc-casutg \
&& apt update \
&& apt install -y default-jdk-headless wget \
&& wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz \
&& tar xf apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz \
&& cd apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION \
&& wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar \
&& wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar -P lib/ \
&& java -cp lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller \
&& ./bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh install $PLUGINS \
&& ./bin/jmeter.sh -n -t extras/Test.jmx -l result.jtl    

